How can I remove an item from the current cart using Velo in Wix?
Product:
Wix Editor
Hi,
I am building a custom cart page where I successfully list all the items in the current cart using a repeater. Each item has a delete button, and I need assistance in removing an item from the cart when this button is clicked.
Based on the updated Velo documentation, I understand that I should use the removeLineItemsFromCurrentCart() API to remove items. However, I'm facing issues retrieving the current cart data. When attempting to use the API, I receive an error message saying that the cart owner could not be found.
Could you please guide me on how to resolve this issue? How can I properly remove an item from the current cart, especially when the user is not logged in?
The error message I recieve:
""Error: message: 'Cart not found: Cannot find cart by ownership'
details:
applicationError:
description: Cannot find cart by ownership
code: OWNED_CART_NOT_FOUND
data: {}"
"
Additional information:
This is the code I have.
--cart.web.js--
`import wixData from 'wix-data';
import { currentUser } from 'wix-users-backend';
import { Permissions, webMethod } from "wix-web-module";
import { currentCart } from "wix-ecom-backend";
import { getCurrentCart } from 'wix-stores-backend';


export const myRemoveLineItemsFromCurrentCartFunction = webMethod(
  Permissions.Anyone,
  async (lineItemIds) => {
    try {
      const updatedCurrentCart =
        await currentCart.removeLineItemsFromCurrentCart(lineItemIds);
      console.log("Success! Line items removed from cart:", updatedCurrentCart);
      return updatedCurrentCart;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      // Handle the error
    }
  },
);

---Front Page----
`
import { myRemoveLineItemsFromCurrentCartFunction } from "backend/cart.web.js";
$item("#deleteItemButton").onClick(() => {
                        console.log("Butona tıklandı.");

                        try {
                            wixData.query('AddToCartInformation')
                                .eq('productID', itemData.productID)
                                .eq('timestamp', itemData.timestamp)
                                .eq('userID', wixUsers.currentUser.id)
                                .find().then((results) => {
                                    if (results.items.length > 0) {
                                        console.log("Veri bulundu:", results.items[0]);

                                    } else {
                                        throw new Error("Ürün bulunamadı");
                                    }

                                    const productIdToUpdateCart = results.items[0].productID;
                                    const quantityToUpdateCart = results.items[0].quantity;
                                    console.log("Product ID: " + productIdToUpdateCart + "Product Quantity: " + quantityToUpdateCart);

                                    getCurrentCart()
                                        .then((cart) => {
                                            console.log("Sepet:", cart);
                                            // Sepet boş mu dolu mu kontrol et
                                            if (cart.lineItems.length > 0) {
                                                // Sepet bilgilerini göster
                                                cart.lineItems.forEach(item => {
                                                    console.log(`Ürün: ${item.name}, Adet: ${item.quantity}`);
                                                    console.log("İtem id: ", item.productId);

                                                    compareProductQuantities(productIdToUpdateCart, quantityToUpdateCart,
                                                        item.productId, item.quantity);
                                                    //removeProductFromCurrentCart(item.productId);

                                                    // Sample lineItemIds array:
                                                    const lineItemIds = [
                                                        results.items[0].productID,
                                                    ];

                                                    
                                                    console.log(cart._id);

                                                   
                                                    myRemoveLineItemsFromCurrentCartFunction(lineItemIds)
                                                        .then((updatedCurrentCart) => {
                                                            
                                                            console.log("Success! Line items removed from cart:", updatedCurrentCart);
                                                            return updatedCurrentCart;
                                                            
                                                        })
                                                        .catch((error) => {
                                                            console.error(error);
                                                            // Handle the error
                                                        });
                                                });
                                            } else {
                                                console.log("Sepet boş");
                                            }

                                        })
                                        .catch((error) => {
                                            console.error("Sepet alınamadı:", error);
                                        });

                                })

                        } catch (error) {
                            console.log(error);
                        }

                    });

`
